# How to retrive only specific fields form MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

For instance I have a database of cars, which have a field called manufacture.

```
car: {
     _id: <ObjectId>,
     manufacture: "Opel",
     model: "Astra"
}
```

How can I get all manufactures without repeating them using the latest implementation official C# driver for MongoDB?

I'd like this to be done in my request to the database, not after.

Comment: Which driver are you using to connect to Mongo? Also, how does the data look within Mongo?

Comment: @Dr Schizo  I use the official driver. The manufacture is a string field of the car entity.

Comment: can we get an example of what it looks like in Mongo? As what you are requesting we really need to know what the data looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
        var db = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("cars");

        FieldDefinition<BsonDocument, string> field = "car.manufacture";
        FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter = new BsonDocument();

        var a = db.DistinctAsync(field, filter).GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Distinct()` method: http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_Distinct.htm

The field name should be passed as a string, some generic MongoDB examples: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Following [some examples](http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/query/), it should look like this: `var result = await collection.Distinct('manufacture');`.

Comment: I can't find this method in the latest version of MongoDB driver for C#, but DistinctAnsync, which takes different parameters.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.